# Grails Spring Security Remember Me

Tags: grails, spring-security

I have a custom auth provider working against a REST API and now want to implement Remember Me functionality.

Here's what I have in Config.groovy:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.providerNames = [
   'zubAuthenticationProvider',
   'rememberMeAuthenticationProvider'
]
grails.plugins.springsecurity.auth.loginFormUrl="/login"
grails.plugins.springsecurity.rememberMe.cookieName="example1"
grails.plugins.springsecurity.rememberMe.key="example1"
```

I can't see the peristent cookie actually being set on successful login.  Am I missing something in config?

** UPDATE **
I can get a cookie to be created if I add:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.rememberMe.persistent = true
```

But, that just leads to another problem of not using a database for login storage.

Thanks in advance,
Todd

Comment: Perhaps no cookie is being set because token repo is "InMemoryTokenRepositoryImpl" when !conf.rememberMe.persistent  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For posterity sake, I'm going with the following--

**Config.groovy**

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.providerNames = [
   'zubAuthenticationProvider',
   'rememberMeAuthenticationProvider'
]

grails.plugins.springsecurity.rememberMe.cookieName="stackoverflow"
grails.plugins.springsecurity.rememberMe.key="_grails_"
grails.plugins.springsecurity.rememberMe.rememberMe.persistent = true
```

**conf/spring/resources.groovy**

```
userDetailsService(com.zub.security.EgUserDetailsService) {
   grailsApplication = ref('grailsApplication')
}
tokenRepository(com.zub.security.EgPersistentTokenRepository) {
    grailsApplication = ref('grailsApplication')
}

def conf = SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig
rememberMeServices(PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices) {
    userDetailsService = ref("userDetailsService")
    key = conf.rememberMe.key
    cookieName = conf.rememberMe.cookieName
    alwaysRemember = conf.rememberMe.alwaysRemember
    tokenValiditySeconds = conf.rememberMe.tokenValiditySeconds
    parameter = conf.rememberMe.parameter
    useSecureCookie = conf.rememberMe.useSecureCookie // false

    tokenRepository = ref('tokenRepository')
    seriesLength = conf.rememberMe.persistentToken.seriesLength // 16
    tokenLength = conf.rememberMe.persistentToken.tokenLength // 16
}
```

EgPersistentTokenRepository is based on GormPersistentTokenRepository but has been updated to make REST calls for CRUD functionality rather than GORM.

Comment: grails.plugins.springsecurity.rememberMe.rememberMe.persistent = true 
Is this a typo: "...rememberMe.rememberMe..." ?