# Grails Remember Me service doesn't work

Tags: grails, spring-security, remember-me

I Have a web application that use Spring security with a ldap.
When I select the check box to activate "remember Me" service, it doesn't work.

After some research I also tried to add the code below by setting 'alwaysRemember' and 'persistent' to true:

```
// Added by the Spring Security Core plugin:
grails.plugins.springsecurity.rememberMe.cookieName='sptest_remember_me'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.rememberMe.alwaysRemember=true
grails.plugins.springsecurity.rememberMe.tokenValiditySeconds=5*60
grails.plugins.springsecurity.rememberMe.parameter='_spring_security_remember_me'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.rememberMe.key='sptest_test'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.rememberMe.useSecureCookie=false
grails.plugins.springsecurity.rememberMe.persistent=true
```

I also tryed to adapt the response below unsuccessfully.

[Grails Spring Security Remember Me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524561/grails-spring-security-remember-me)

I want to know how to implement correctly this feature.

Thanks

Comment: Is the tokenValiditySeconds time too short, just 5 minutes? You can watch the browser cookie cookieName='sptest_remember_me' to see if cookie has been set, if yes, you can debug into RememberMeAuthenticationFilter to see what happened.